# Is strpos requires something else

Tags: php, string

I have string like this -

```
$existingStr = "Test# 123456 Opened by System";
```

I want 3 different parts of string like this -

```
1st part : Test#
2nd part : 123456
3rd part : rest of the part
```

Hence first I get position of hash then I am looking for space position from increment hash position value but its not giving me next space position.

Code -

```
echo $existingStr."<br>";
$strhashPos = strpos($existingStr,"#");
echo $strhashPos."<br>";
$strincementhashPos = $strhashPos + 1;
echo $strincementhashPos ."<br>";

$strspacePos = strpos($existingStr,' ',$strincementhashPos);
echo $strspacePos."<br>";

$tempWOId = $strspacePos-$strincementhashPos;
echo $tempWOId."<br>";

$strFirstPart = substr($existingStr,0,$strincementhashPos);
echo $strFirstPart."<br>";

$strSecondPart = substr($existingStr,$strincementhashPos,$tempWOId);
echo $strSecondPart."<br>";

$strThirdPart = substr($existingStr,$strspacePos,-1);
echo $strThirdPart."<br>";
```

Due to which it gives me wrong $strSecondPart ... Can someone suggest me what is wrong with getting next space position.Also suggest some optimised or alternatives ...

Comment: One line solution: preg_match('/^([^#]*#)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/su', $str, $parts);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use php [`explode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

i.e. :

```
php > $existingStr = "Test# 123456 Opened by System";
php > $strToArr = explode(' ', $existingStr);
php > $strFirstPart = $strToArr[0];
php > echo $strFirstPart . "<br />";
Test#<br />
php > $strSecondPart = $strToArr[1];
php > echo $strSecondPart . "<br />";
123456<br />
```

And then to catch the rest of the string, use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) functions :

```
php > $strThirdPart = implode(" ", array_slice($strToArr, 2));
php > echo $strThirdPart;
Opened by System
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Following the @Evert comment : `explode()` function can take a third argument to define a limit.This provides a great shortcut !

i.e. :

```
$existingStr = "Test# 123456 Opened by System";
print_r(explode(' ', $existingStr, 3));
```

Output :

> Array
>   (
>      [0] => Test#
>      [1] => 123456
>      [2] => Opened by System
>   )

Comment: Just use the third explode argument : `explode(' ', $input, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$existingStr = "Test# 123456 Opened by System";
$items = explode(' ', $existingStr);
$first = $items[0];
$second = $items[1];
unset($items[0]);
unset($items[1]);
$third = join($items);
echo $first."\n";
echo $second."\n";
echo $third."\n";
```

here is the result:

```
localhost:~$ php -f aaaa
Test#
123456
OpenedbySystem
```